# Is there any function faster than find()?

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays "data1" "data2". For each line of "data1", I would find the number of lines that respects the condition on strings and numbers (see below) between "data1" and "data2". I tried to use the function "find" but I find that it is not very fast. Is there a function that is faster than "find" ? Here is my code:

```
for lineData1 = 1 : size(data1,1) 

        vectorData = find( ( cell2mat(data2(2:size(data2,1),1)) == data1{lineData1,2} | cell2mat(data2(2:size(data2,1),2)) == data1{lineData1,2} ) & ...
            strcmp(data2(2:size(data2,1),4),data1{lineData1,3}) & ...
            strcmp(data2(2:size(data2,1),5),data1{lineData1,4}) & ...
            strcmp(data2(2:size(data2,1),6),data1{lineData1,5}) & ...
            cell2mat(data2(2:size(data2,1),7)) == data1{lineData1,6} & ...
            cell2mat(data2(2:size(data2,1),8)) == data1{lineData1,7} );
        %%% vectorData = vectorData + 1;

        data1{lineData1,1} = size(vectorData,1);
    end
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Give us sample input data to work with?

Comment: I am sure that's not the `find` which slows down this code. Run it using `profile`, it's probably `strcmp` or `cell2mat` which slows down your code. Nevertheless, `size(find(x),1)` could be replaced with `sum(x)` assuming x is a logical vector.

Comment: Yeah, string operations such as `strcmp` are very slow, and `cell2mat` conversion will also be slowing your code down. `find` is a very standard function, and there's no reason to suspect it is at all slow. If there was another function that did the same as `find` but was faster, it would be called `find`! If you can explain what you are trying to do there may be a faster alternative other than the comparisons you are doing.

Comment: I would also suggest placing all of the strings you want to compare with into two cell arrays and run a single `strcmp`.  Calling `strcmp` three times in one loop iteration would make your code glacial.